# java installation error when i try to find the version

Tags: java, linux, bash

When I try to install Java on my Linux machine I am getting message already installed but I still cannot retrieve `java -version`. Please help.

```
[root@localhost Downloads]# rpm -ivh jre-8u31-linux-i586.rpm 
Preparing...                   ###########################################
[100%]  package jre1.8.0_31-1.8.0_31-fcs.i586 is already installed
[root@localhost Downloads]# whereis java
java: /etc/java /usr/lib/java    /usr/share/java 
[root@localhost Downloads]# java-version
bash:    java-version: command not found 
[root@localhost Downloads]# java -version
bash: java: command not found
```

Thanks in advance! 
Kumar

Comment: Try `/usr/lib/java -version` - or put the path path to the java executable to your `PATH` variable and run `java -version` again

Comment: see https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/49060/how-to-make-oracle-jdk-and-jre-as-default-java-in-fedora-20/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`.
You can do this by executing:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07/bin
```

You should replace `/usr/java/jdk1.5.0_07` with you java installation path.

For more details check the link below:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: thank you all for your support

Comment: i can see java -version now but if i type echo $java_HOME i am unable to see the paths still it is blank do you help me to set the path for java home

Comment: @keshav nagaraj you should export JAVA_HOME environment variable.

export JAVA_HOME=path to your java instalation

Comment: @ Fildor, thanks, you are absolutely right. I will edit the answer.